# Can’t write scripts in react

Tags: reactjs, remix.run

So, I’m making a website with react&remi.js , and everything is set up and ready to go just one thing, I can’t use javascript functions and stuff inside .jsx file anyone knows how?

i tried to put the script out of the “return” but it doesn’t get the function name, doesn’t do anything, here's how i did it..

```
export default function Index() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div id="myNav" class="overlay">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <div class="overlay-content">
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <a href="#">Clients</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h2>testing the nav</h2>
      <span className="spanText" onclick={openNav}>&#9776; open</span>
    </div>

  );
  function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
  }

  function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
  }
}
```

Comment: try just using .js files.

Comment: update your question to show what you've tried. Sounds like you're close, but have a syntax error.

Comment: are you using webpack?

Comment: i edited the message and added the code i used before and didn't work, no i can't use .js cuas i need react inside so.., also, no, im not using webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add on to what Tomas said:

1. In react elements, it should be `className=`, not `class=`
2. In react, to invoke functions, you should use `onClick={/* your code */}`, using {} instead of ""
3. Also, be careful about invoking functions when declaring your element rather than at the time the event is run:

`onClick={closeNav()}` will call closeNav when defining the react element, and then throw an error when you actually click on the element

`onClick={closeNav}` will not invoke the function until you click on the element

`onClick={() => closeNav()}` will also work

Here's code with all those changes applied:

```
export default function Index() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div id="myNav" className="overlay">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" className="closebtn" onClick={closeNav}>
          &times;
        </a>
        <div className="overlay-content">
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <a href="#">Clients</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <h2>testing the nav</h2>
      <span className="spanText" onClick={openNav}>
        &#9776; open
      </span>
    </div>
  );
  function openNav() {
    alert('open');
    document.getElementById('myNav').style.width = '100%';
  }

  function closeNav() {
    alert('close');
    document.getElementById('myNav').style.width = '0%';
  }
}
```

Here's a working sandbox with this code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-scratchpad-forked-qtfb8x?file=/src/index.js

FWIW - the problems you're running into are all react related, remix isn't causing the issues here.

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use `javascript` inside a JSX file.
Plus `onclick` should be `onClick` for the click event

```js
export default function Index() {
  const closeNav = () => { /... };

  return (
    <div className="closebtn" onClick="closeNav">&times;</div>
  )
}
```